# Does the JOptionPane showMessageDialog method automatically instantiate the objects needed for this dialogue box

Tags: java

I know when we use the JOptionPane class, we don't have to instantiate it as this class was designed to make quick simple on the fly dialogue boxes. Does the `showMessageDialog method` automatically instantiate the objects needed for this dialogue box?

Comment: Short answer:  yes...I mean, it would have to come from *somewhere*...although I admit I'm a bit puzzled about what you're asking.  Are you asking if the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` handles all of the necessary plumbing to get the display box to show up for you?

Comment: Yeah basically, I mean the panels, the buttons, and the action listeners must be created somewhere. Was just wondering where all of this instantiated?

Comment: Hard to see where else they could possibly come from, or why you're even asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` creates all of the necessary components and bits necessary to display the dialog boxes.  If it didn't, it wouldn't be a very good method.

One can think of this method as a factory method; if you give it certain parameters it has a duty of producing an interface which fills in those values in specific locations.  This factory method handles the creation of the GUI components necessary to work, and thus the end user doesn't need to worry about it.

...But if the end user *really* wants to worry about it, [they're more than welcome to go down the rabbit hole if they want to.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.Icon%29)